# Store date without time in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date-formatting

I have a table in oracle DB that contains data the payment date look like this :

```
Payment table :
field_date
11.03.2014 00:00:00
20.03.2014 00:00:00
```

I want to remove time (00:00:00), but stay keep type of data. to do that :
 1. I have create new table with name xyz table.

```
create table xyz (date_1 date)
```

2. Insert contains of payment table to xyz table

```
    insert into xyz select field_date from payment;
```

or

```
insert into xyz select trunc(field_date) from payment;
```

After to do that, field date_1 on xyz table stay contain time. how to do that?

Comment: Oracle DATE data type always contains time part.

Comment: Oracle does not store dates in the format you see. It stores it internally in 7 bytes with each byte storing different components of the datetime value.

If you want to display, use TO_CHAR with proper FORMAT MODEL.

While inserting, use TO_DATE with proper FORMAT MODEL.